# Python replace / with \

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, path

I write some simple Python script and I want to replace all characters `/` with `\` in text variable. I have problem with character `\`, because it is escape character. When I use `replace()` method:

```
unix_path='/path/to/some/directory'
unix_path.replace('/','\\')
```

then it returns following string: `\\path\\to\\some\\directory`. Of course, I can't use: `unix_path.replace('/','\')`, because `\` is escape character.

When I use regular expression:

```
import re
unix_path='/path/to/some/directory'
re.sub('/', r'\\', unix_path)
```

then it has same results: `\\path\\to\\some\\directory`. I would like to get this result: `\path\to\some\directory`.

Note: I aware of `os.path`, but I did not find any feasible method in this module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed something: it is *shown* as `\\` by the Python interpreter, but your result is correct: `'\\'`is just how Python represents the character `\` in a normal string. That's strictly equivalent to `\` in a raw string, e.g. `'some\\path` is same as `r'some\path'`.

And also: Python on windows knows very well how to use `/` in paths.

You can use the following trick though, if you want your dislpay to be OS-dependant:

```
In [0]: os.path.abspath('c:/some/path')
Out[0]: 'c:\\some\\path'
```

Comment: Try `r'\'` in a shell.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need it for some reports at Linux samba server and Windows users will read these reports. Sugested tricks are nice, but I will not need them in this case. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
>>> unix_path='/path/to/some/directory'
>>> unix_path.replace('/', '\\')
'\\path\\to\\some\\directory'
>>> print(_)
\path\to\some\directory
```

And, more than likely, you should be using something in `os.path` instead of messing with this sort of thing manually.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
unix_path= '/path/to/some/directory'

print(unix_path.replace('/','\\'))
```

result:

```
\path\to\some\directory
```