# Changing `\` to `/`

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I would like to go the opposite direction of the post [Python replace / with \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992740/python-replace-with).

For example, the path to desktop:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop') 
print(desktop)
```

The above code prints "`C:\Users\r2d2w\Desktop`". I would like to convert it to "`C:/Users/r2d2w/Desktop`". How can this be done? The line `desktop.replace("\", "/")` will not work and will give error "EOL while scanning string literal".

Comment: Did you look at the other answers in the duplicate you yourself linked? The second-highest voted one (posted by me, ironically) says how to do the `replace` correctly. All you'd need to do is switch the search string and the replacement string.

Comment: You can try this ```print("".join(["/" if i == '\\' else i for i in desktop]))``` instead of using ```.replace```

Answer (score -1):

Have you already tried to do:

```
desktop.replace("\\", "/")
```

?